# Bottom bar not aligned at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to use `com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar` but even after setting gravity at bottom it is getting hidden behind the action bar. Please solve my error.
Thank You.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
            />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_color_changing"
        app:bb_behavior="shifting|shy|underNavbar" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` it will work!

Comment: Hey thanks!! I'm new to android studio. It was a silly mistake :D 
Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @Sharzil Shaikh you can accept the answer if it solved your problem! ^_^

Comment: Hey Sorry, I didn't noticed that.. Done!! :D